# pasting excel vba array from memory to sheet takes long time to complete

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, performance

I have an array in memory that I have set to 10 by 800 cells. I fill this with information I pull from the web in VBA, and that all works fine.
When I'm done filling my array, I paste it to sheet - and that takes about 10 seconds, which I think is very long for 8,000 cells.

Couple of things to note:

- Some cells will contain long text strings (several thousands of characters long), and the sheet automatically wraps them, even if I say "Sheet1.Cells.WrapText = False" before pasting. Unwrapping them will also take some time.
- When I tried to make the array considerably smaller, but still kept the same data in it (by combining data of three cells into one and getting rid of deliberately empty columns), the time to paste didn't change.
- I've tried it on Excel 2010 and 2013, but both are 32bit. I know on 64bit it'll likely be faster, but it should run OK on 32bit as well.

Should I just accept the fact that it will take a while? I know 10 seconds seems arbitrary, but considering that pulling the data to fill the array takes considerably less time, and then having Excel 'hang' for 10 seconds, is a bad experience for all the people that will run this.

Thanks for any guidance!

Code:

```
If Tracker.Count = 0 Then
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Sheet1.Activate
Sheet1.UsedRange.Delete
Sheet1.Range(Cells(1,1), Cells(10, 800)).WrapText = False
Dim t#
t = Timer
Sheet1.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(rawSht), UBound(rawSht, 2)) = rawSht
Sheet1.UsedRange.WrapText = False
Debug.Print Timer - t

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: If you want to get the help you need, I think you need to provide a lot more details. I don't see the line were you place code into the worksheet from the array. Since that's the part you say takes a while, why don't you show that? What type of array is it? Have you tried using a Variant? Are you sure it's the paste operation that is the slow step? How do you know? Have tried it on more than one computer? Can you set up sample data so that someone else can try it?

Comment: @JasperD: Try this and let us know. Once the 8000 cells are successfully copied to a excel sheet, try copying those 8000 cells to new sheet  manually and see how long it takes?

Comment: @CSS - good point. Takes exactly the same amount of time... Sheet1.UsedRange.Copy Destination:=Sheet2.Range("A1") ; I guess I'll just have to live with it then? Could it be due to some cells containing a LOT of text? Should I set the cell format to text instead of general?

Comment: @Tony: can you read code? In order of appearance; the line is clearly there: Sheet1.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(rawSht), UBound(rawSht, 2)) = rawSht; 2 dimensional array (as you can see from that line as well); how would i use a variant for a 2-dimensional array?; yes, i am sure, as in the code I check how long that part takes; yes, as mentioned on excel 2010 and 2013; not really.

Comment: It would help if you showed where you defined your variables. Variants are designed to write to/read from cells (1D or 2D) and they also allow array manipulations. But for performance as much as possible should be done as array manipulations, and then when you’re done with that, fill the cells. Cells in Excel have many properties, so manipulations in the cells will always be the slower then array manipulation. I would suggest that you do some tests in which the number of characters per cell is made much smaller to see if that’s what’s causing the delay.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Tony. It's just defined as RawSht and then redim'd to the dimensions found (without preserve, which isn't necessary in this case). There's no manipulation done other than filling the array and pasting it to sheet. Good point on trying an array with shorter values; If I simply fill an array with 10 rows of 800 columns of random 20 digit numbers, the paste is 0.01 second.... I guess it's having a large number of cells that have hundreds or thousands of characters in them that's causing it here... darn.

Comment: It could be that Excel has some issues parsing your data. Set the text format on the destination range or try to add a quote in front of the  strings.

Comment: @JasperD i’m glad the source of the problem has emerged. Next time you post a question please provide the code for every item relevant to your question, including dimensioning of the variables. It may seem clear to you, but it is not the others, at least not to me. I believe that will reduce the length of the comment sections, which is a good thing because stack overflow discourages extended conversations like this